# Confusion regarding the use of "to be"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

1) "Do you want the designs made in Photoshop?" 
2) "Do you want the designs to be made in photoshop?"

Which of these sentences is correct and why? also, what is the difference between the two? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentence 2) refers to prospective designs. "Shall we make them in Photoshop?"

Sentence 1) could refer to prospective designs, or it could refer to designs which have already been made in Photoshop.

The situation would indicate the meaning.

(As a side note, sentence 2, "Do you want the designs [which are] to be made in Photoshop?" could have a different, less likely meaning:
"Do you want the designs which we are going to make in Photoshop?"
That is, we are definitely making designs in Photoshop. Do you want them?)